# TFS - Who enabled/disabled multiple checkouts?

Tags: tfs, multiple-checkout

In our Team foundation server, we use to keep multiple checkouts disabled. however, recently, someone enabled it and we can't figure that out who enabled it.

Is there any log available somewhere which could tell us who enabled or disabled the multiple checkouts?

TFS server version we are using is 2013 and Visual Studio versions are at 2019

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, we do not have this kind of user Audit log generated in TFS 2013.

Multiple checkout in TFS can only be [enabled or disabled at the project level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242869%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). To enable or disable it, someone with appreciate access needs to use Team Explorer to navigate to:

(project) -> Team Project Settings -> Source Control -> Checkout Settings and toggle on the "Allow Multiple Check-Outs" box.

> To configure check-out settings, you must have the **Edit
>   project-level information** set to **Allow**.

We could narrow down the scope of users. He should at lease own above permission, usually be  a team project Administrator.  Aka, if you want to avoid this scenario, you should pay attention to assign such permission to properly persons.

If you insist on finding out who did this. I'm afraid you have to dig into database, this kind of info may stored in a table /column (not 100% sure).  And highly not suggest to make your hands dirty when touching database, it may cause database crashed and lose support from Microsoft. Better to submit a support ticket and involve Microsoft engineer to help you look at it.

In my opinion, it's no need to spend time on this if it only occurs one time. Maybe just some one mishandling it. Use a more strict permission setting to prevent this kind of things occurred again.

Comment: Thanks, I also thought here might not be a log available, but checking if I am wrong!